# "surname" is alphabetically sorted from a list

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to check if the "surname" is alphabetically sorted from a list.
the page I have to test is : [page](https://www.libraccio.it/src/?FT=andrea+camilleri&CH=libraccio&MF=&DF=1120&UF=&PX=1&SRT=205&MP=%7Bmp%7D)

I can get the text from the product box and split string to get only the surname but I don't know how to check if is sorted A-Z in the list.

I tried with the code below but is not working

```
    Get Ready Element      ${element_result_autore}
    ${aut}   Get Text   ${element_result_autore}
    ${autore}  Split String    ${aut}  
    log  ${autore}[1]
    @{list_result}  Get WebElements    ${element_result_autore}
    FOR  ${item}  IN  @{list_result}
    ${result}  Check If Order By Alphabetical  ${autore}  ${item.text}
    ${autore}   Run Keyword If   ${result}==True     Set Variable    ${item.text}
    ...    ELSE      FAIL  the result is not order ${item.text} - ${autore}
    END
```

Comment: "how to check if is sorted A-Z in the list": Please explain what this means, possibly with example(s).

Comment: It would help if you could create a [mcve] that didn't require scraping an actual site. Can you give us an example with some hard-coded lists of names?

Answer (score 0):

I have 25 items and i need to get only the surname, below the code.
what i need is to get "Aliberti" from 'author':'Carmelo Aliberti' in this product.
therefore get a list with all the surname from all the 25 items.

$(document).ready(setTimeout(function () {
            OnAfterSearchInitialize_ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR();

        }, 100));

    function OnAfterSearchInitialize_ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR() {

        var isAlgNull = false;

        var indexUsed = null;
        var queryId = null;

        if (!isAlgNull) {
            indexUsed = 'dev_Libraccio_Physical_Author_asc';
            queryId = 'f4fad3ce974ff8c90a441b9f2700d949';
        }

        var positionIX = 1;
        var idProd = '9788894894523';

        // Aggancio contextMenu e Clicked
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_lTitleonContext').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_lTitleonContext').click(function () {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });

        // Aggancio contextMenu e Clicked
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_bGoDetailonContext').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_bGoDetailonContext').click(function () {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });

        // Aggancio contextMenu e Clicked
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_lTitleEbookonContext').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_lTitleEbookonContext').click(function () {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });

        // Aggancio contextMenu e Clicked
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_bGoDetailEbookonContext').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });
        $('.ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_bGoDetailEbookonContext').click(function () {
            appClickedObjectIDsAfterSearch(isAlgNull, indexUsed, queryId, positionIX, idProd);
        });

    }



                
    
                    
        
                        
            
        
                    
        
            
                
                    
                                Aggiungi a una lista
                                +
                    
                
            
            
                
                
                
                
                Andrea Camilleri
            
            Autore Carmelo Aliberti,Anno 2018,Editore BastogiLibri

```
        <div class="prices fullprice">
                    
            <div class="prn">
                        
                
                
                <span class="sellpr">€ 12,00</span>
                
            
                    </div>
            
        
                </div>
        <div class="insight"><div>ty=I s=1 rel=1,1</div>
```

op=N s=1 q=6(0+6-0) g=3

```
        <div class="prodcart">
            
            <div class="option opN">
                <span class="available">3gg</span>
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_C_C_PL1_RP_ctl00_PR_bBuyN" class="acquista-nuovo buybtn buynow" rel="nofollow" data-tracking-info="{
```

'event':'addToCart',
"ecommerce":{
'currencyCode':'EUR',
"add":{
"products":[{
'name':'Andrea Camilleri',
'id':'9788894894523',
'price':'12.00',
'brand':'BastogiLibri',
'category':'Libri / Letteratura: storia e critica',
'variant':'fisico',
'productcover_price':'12.00',
'productdiscount_price':'12.00',
'product_discount':'0%',
'productused_price':'0',
'yearEdition':'2018',
**'author':'Carmelo Aliberti',**
'series':'Testimonianze',
'publisher':'BastogiLibri',
'availabilityUsed':'NO',
'promoid':'0'
,
'quantity':'1'
}]}}}" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$C$C$PL1$RP$ctl00$PR$bBuyN','')">Compra nuovo